# how to create a treemap chart in android

Tags: android, charts, treemap

I have an android application thats take data from sqlite database

and display the data in a simple gridview and it's work

but I want to remove gridview and have a treemap chart

the treemap chart is displaying the result with custom squares size and color

upon a specific value , when the value is bigger the square will be bigger and most dark color

**I want it like this!**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is [this](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-treemap) tool on github for displaying treemaps, conveniently called **android-treemap**, but there are tons of other ways to do that.

Comment: yes man ... I have this example

but its very diffecult and complex

I wasted 2 days to try understanding this example but I can not

in this example the item add manually and the colors does NOT change upon the value :(

Comment: but this example are exactly what I want if I can change the color upon the value pairs with title

Comment: the [documentation](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-treemap/blob/master/squarified-treemaps.pdf) seems pretty good, however there's [another](https://github.com/UCSBGeoSpatial/TreeMapprMobile) java treemap-for android. 

You should post some code of your gridview.

Comment: I have read the documentation but it's does not help :(

and the treemapper source crash :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap) with web view.

Comment: thank you for reply .. but I want to build it in the local activity